# Is it possible to stringify a variadic macro into a comma delimited list of strings?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

In essence I want to write

`MACRO(a, b, c)`

and have it result in

`"a","b","c"`

I tried using `#__VA_ARGS__`, but it results in one string containing all arguments:

`"a, b, c"`

which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify if the call is always 3 arguments `MACRO(a, b, c)` or if it could contain any parameters.

Comment: Looks like you'd need something recursive: `#define MACRO(a, ...) #a, MACRO(__VA_ARGS__)`. You need a special case anyway for the last argument as it's not followed by a comma.

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/NP3Hdm)

Answer (score -3):

```
#define MACRO3(a, b, c) #a,#b,#c
```

Make one for each argument count you might use

Comment: That isn’t a variadic macro.